# Ctrl+6 does not edit alternate buffer in Vim running in Terminal on macOS

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

On my macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, I launch `vim` in Terminal and enter the following commands in Vim.

```
:e foo.txt
:e bar.txt
```

Now if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>, it does not go back to the alternate file `foo.txt`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> works fine and does go back to the alternate file `foo.txt`.

Every other Vim, MacVim, or GVim I have used goes back to the alternate file on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>. Why does it not work with `vim` of macOS?

Here is my vim version details:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    -mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
-arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           -mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     -termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      -terminal
+builtin_terms   +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    -keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        -langmap         +printer         +visual
-conceal         +libcall         -profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             -rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
-emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            -mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
-farsi           -mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

Comment: first of course you should check for a mapping on the combination: `:map <c-6>?`. Then it would be worth to check what keycode vim recieves. Press `C-v` in insert mode and then press `C-6`. It may be your terminal that sends a different keycode.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo `:map <c-6>?` says `No mapping found`. In insert mode, when I press `C-v`, the `^` appears in the text in the editor. Then I press `C-6` and nothing happens. It behaves as if Vim did not receive `C-6` at all.

Comment: hmm strange, and `C-v` -> `C-S-6` does work?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Yes, `control-shift-6` does work and switches to alternate buffer. `control-v` and `control-shift-6` displays `^^` in insert mode as expected. But `control-6` does not work. Today I noticed that on macOS Terminal (with or without Vim running) produces an audible bell (beep) sound. I am guessing macOS terminal is interpreting the `control-6` and doing something with it, erroring out and reporting an audible bell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior according to the help:

```
5. Mac Lack                     *mac-lack*

In a terminal CTRL-^ needs to be entered as Shift-Control-6.  CTRL-@ as
Shift-Control-2.
```

Comment: This is true with an American keyboard. With my Italian keyboard, Shift -Ctrl-^ and Shift Ctrl-@ work as expected. In this layout, ^ is the rightmost key of the first row and @ is where you might find ;

Answer (score 3):

seems like vim actually maps `<C-^>` which is what most terminals send when you press `<C-6>`. The mac terminal does not send `<C-^>` but nothing. `<c-s-6>` is most likely working because `<s-6>` is `^`.